# Detect specific sequence of string in a column from a list

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to extract out specific strings using a list. Would that be possible in Python?

I have this list here:

```
currency = ['SGD', 'GBP', 'USD', 'EUR']
```

And if any of these strings appear in a column, I would want a new column to be created with the respective currency. This is my intended ouput:

**Intended Output**

```
Name         Currency        Currency_updated    
0   Tom    RANDOM_SGD_2017         SGD
1   nick    TEST_EUR_1381          EUR
2   krish   FORFUN GBP             GBP
3   jack    NAs                    <blank>
```

**Reproducible Example**

```
import pandas as pd 

data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'Currency':['RANDOM_SGD_2017', 'TEST_EUR_1381', 'FORFUN GBP', 'NAs']} 

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Dataframe Used**

```
     Name       Currency
0   Tom RANDOM_SGD_2017
1   nick    TEST_EUR_1381
2   krish   FORFUN GBP
3   jack    NAs
```

Comment: If you do not want to match EUR in EUROPE, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55275748/3832970).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a function that operates on the rows of your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

def f(row):
  for elem in currency:
      if elem in row['Currency']:
           return elem

currency = ['SGD', 'GBP', 'USD', 'EUR']
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'Currency':['RANDOM_SGD_2017', 'TEST_EUR_1381', 'FORFUN GBP', 'NAs']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Currency_Updated'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print(df)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
    Name         Currency Currency_Updated
0    Tom  RANDOM_SGD_2017              SGD
1   nick    TEST_EUR_1381              EUR
2  krish       FORFUN GBP              GBP
3   jack              NAs             None
```

Comment: @Javier you're welcome, you may accept the answer that helped you, cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with `join` and `|` for regex `OR` - `'SGD|GBP|USD|EUR'` means `'SGD' or 'GBP' or 'USD' or 'EUR'`

```
pat = '|'.join(currency)
df['Currency_updated'] = df['Currency'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False)
print (df)
    Name         Currency Currency_updated
0    Tom  RANDOM_SGD_2017              SGD
1   nick    TEST_EUR_1381              EUR
2  krish       FORFUN GBP              GBP
3   jack              NAs              NaN
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer, may I ask why did you used '|' in your first line? what does it do?

Answer (score 3):

Another method could be using [*re.search()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```
import re
df['Currency_updated'] = df['Currency'].apply(lambda x: re.search('|'.join(currency), x).group(0) if x!='NAs' else None)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `str.extract` with

```
(?<![^\W_])(SGD|GBP|USD|EUR)(?![^\W_])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jTizE5/2/).

Note that the `(?<![^\W_])` / `(?![^\W_])` are unambiguous word boundaries that also consider `_` (underscores) as "non-word" chars, so `EUR` in `_EUR_` is considered a whole word.

In Python, the regex can be built using `r'(?<![^\W_])({})(?![^\W_])'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, currency)))`, with `re.escape`, just in case you may have `$` or other special chars in the currency names, like `CA$`.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack', 'meg', 'sarah'], 'Currency':['RANDOM_SGD_2017', 'TEST_EUR_1381', 'FORFUN GBP', 'NAs', 'More fun in EUROPE', 'And MUSDA thing']}
currency = ['SGD', 'GBP', 'USD', 'EUR']
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

rx = r'(?<![^\W_])({})(?![^\W_])'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, currency)))
df['Currency_updated'] = df['Currency'].str.extract(rx, expand=False)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    Name            Currency Currency_updated
0    Tom     RANDOM_SGD_2017              SGD
1   nick       TEST_EUR_1381              EUR
2  krish          FORFUN GBP              GBP
3   jack                 NAs              NaN
4    meg  More fun in EUROPE              NaN
5  sarah     And MUSDA thing              NaN
```